# Checking the parameter inside a Action List

Tags: c#, list, action

I was wondering if it is possible to reference a parameter inside a List, for a example

```
if ( listOfActions[index].SecondParameter == x ){
    do stuff
}
```

to be honest I could not understand much of the [Action Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but here is what I got so far:

```
List<Action> musicSequence = new List<Action>();
...
void addBulletToList (string direction, float time){
    musicSequence.Add ( ()=>musicControl.spawnBullet(direction, time) );
}

void spawnBullet(string direction, float time){
    go = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(direction));
}
//And in my main function it would be something like this
if ( CurrentMusicTime equals the time parameter in musicSequence[index] ){
    execute musicSequence[index]
    next index
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `float time` is unique per action, you could consider using a `Dictionary<float, Action>` to store the corresponding action, since what you are currently attempting is impossible.

```
Dictionary<float, Action> musicSequence = new Dictionary<float, Action>();

void addBulletToList (string direction, float time){
    musicSequence.Add(time, () => musicControl.spawnBullet(direction, time));
}

void spawnBullet(string direction, float time){
    go = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(direction));
}

if (musicSequence.Keys.Contains(CurrentMusicTime)){
    musicSequence[CurrentMusicTime]();
    next index
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about this dictionary structure! Very interesting.

I had a few problems making my chronometer match the key value but after a few smelly codes it worked out ~UEHUEHuEHUE

thx again ~s2

Comment: Glad it helped!  Sorry for the lack of an exact match. It was my best guess based on what you described above.